# How do I prevent jamming?

Tags: mechwarrior-online

In MechWarrior Online I have a Jagermech JM6-DD with two AC2s and two Ultra AC5s. When I fire the autocannons simultaneously, the Ultra AC5 jams. How do I prevent the Ultra Autocannon/5 from jamming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature called chain firing, where instead of firing all the cannons at once, it fires them one by one. I had this problem but I never jam when I use chainfiring. Chainfiring is one of the most useful mechanics in the game, because it also prevents heating issues.

Comment: Just don't spray and pray.